# scrapyd has error : exceptions.TypeError: <XXX: XXX object> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I use scrapyd to run scrapy jobs,there is error :
I don't know why would this happen??
Please help me.

```
ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method ?.item_scraped of <scrapy.contrib.feedexport.FeedExporter object at 0x7fbed853fe10>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/user1/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "/home/user1/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 215, in _itemproc_finished
        item=output, response=response, spider=spider)
      File "/home/user1/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/signalmanager.py", line 23, in send_catch_log_deferred
        return signal.send_catch_log_deferred(*a, **kw)
      File "/home/user1/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/signal.py", line 53, in send_catch_log_deferred
        *arguments, **named)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/home/user1/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 139, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)
      File "/home/user1/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/xlib/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 54, in robustApply
        return receiver(*arguments, **named)
      File "/home/user1/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/feedexport.py", line 190, in item_scraped
        slot.exporter.export_item(item)
      File "/home/user1/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/exporter/__init__.py", line 111, in export_item
        self.file.write(self.encoder.encode(itemdict))
      File "/home/user1/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/serialize.py", line 89, in encode
        return super(ScrapyJSONEncoder, self).encode(o)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
        chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
        return _iterencode(o, 0)
      File "/home/user1/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/serialize.py", line 109, in default
        return super(ScrapyJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
        raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
    exceptions.TypeError: <Store: Store object> is not JSON serializable
```

items.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.djangoitem import DjangoItem
from place.models import Address

class AddressItem(DjangoItem):
    django_model = Address
```

pipeline.py

```
class FoodPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if isinstance(item, AddressItem):
            product = item.save(commit=False)
            product_exist = Address.objects.filter(add=product.add)
            if product_exist:
                product.id     = product_exist[0].id             
            product.save()
            return item
```

Comment: Can you show the complete code of your spider, or/and example items that are returned/yield? Thanks.

Comment: ok,I edit it. And I solve this error by adding this :````EXTENSIONS = {'scrapy.contrib.feedexport.FeedExporter': None}```` in settings.py , But I not sure if this will cause another problem? Could you give me some advice